# Can loops like this one be algorithmically transformed into multiplication

Tags: formal-languages, optimization, programming-languages, program-optimization

Are there known techniques for converting a loop like the following to an `if` and a multiplication?

```
while (x < 0) {
    x += 60;
}
```

It seems clear that this could be replaced with something like the following

```
if (x < 0) {
    x += f(x, 60);
}
```

where `f` contains no loops, presumably using multiplication. This would have the benefit of being faster for sufficiently large negative numbers.

Is there a well understood algorithm for finding `f` for an arbitrary loop of this form?

Comment: Clang seems to be able to do that: https://godbolt.org/g/oZaf4Y (Note: it also replaces the division with an inverse scaled multiplication, which is a very common way of eliminating division  by known constants.)

Comment: One approach could be to use known techniques for loop invariant synthesis (discovering a loop invariant).  The loop invariant might characterize the value of `x` after existing the loop, which in some cases might enable replacing the entire loop with a simple function `f` as you seek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name for this optimization seems to be **induction variable elimination**, there are some nice slides explaining the idea [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS380C/2013/lectures/strengthReduction.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is find a number, which when multiplied by 60 and added to x, will bring x above (or equal to) your chosen limit.

This number can be found by dividing the difference between x and 0 by 60, and taking the ceiling of the resulting value. The general function would be:

```
f(x,y) = ceil((limit-x) / y) * y
```

Note that when your limit is 0 the expression simplifies to:

```
f(x,y) = ceil(-x / y) * y
```

Comment: Yes, that is how to simplify the expression. But OP is not looking for the simplification; rather, the algorithm for deriving that solution given (say) a control-flow graph of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I went about it-
We know the loop keeps adding 60, (let the general case be known as k) till the input becomes positive.
Let input be x, we observe that when x lies between -59 and 0, we add 60 once, i.e when x-1 lies between -60 and  -1 we add 60 once.
We can say from the observation that when x belongs to `[n*k,(n-1)*k)` we multiply k by n.
`f(x,k)= n*k if x belongs to [n*k,(n-1))` 
 From the above we can easily get the function `f(x,k)=ceil(|x-1|/k)*k`.
These steps are mere implementation of the principles which  Cody posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
if(x < 0) {
    x = 60 - ((-x) % 60);
}
```

Comment: I think OP asks for algorithm that has only additions/multiplications. Maybe inverting the number, but that requires floating point.